# how to fix error "could not read from remote repository"?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket account.
I set up ssh and every thing is ok but when I enter `git pull` and some other commands,it gives this error:

```
fatal: 'git@bitbucket.org/****/****' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you say "everything is OK" what do you mean? Have you pulled from this repository before?

Comment: It's about checking commands like `ssh *@bitbucket.org`

Comment: It could be that your URL is wrong; hard to tell without more details. Is there supposed to be a ".git" on the end of your URL? Are you using the exact URL that bitbucket told you to?

Comment: @issac thanks for your answers(questions?) but solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved.
problem is happened when I was editing `.bashrc`.
I just put git@bitbucket.org`/`usrname/... instead of git@bitbucket.org`:`usrname/... in url value.